# how to do batch processing in wordpress for downloading CSV file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, batch-processing

I need to fetch approx 6000 records from my WordPress database. When i am using simple query of WordPress $wbpd->get_result('Query') .

It's giving me the error of "Server timeout error". So, I want to use batch processing concept for this.

Below is my code.

```
 $start_from = 0;
  $i = 1;
  $total_pages = ceil($total_records_result / 10);
  for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++){ 
        $start_from = ($i - 1) * 10;   

  $querystr = "select 
               p.order_id,
               p.order_item_id,
               p.order_item_name,
               p.order_item_type,
               po.post_status
               from
               wp_woocommerce_order_items as p,...........;

   $querystr .= " group by p.order_item_id order by p.order_id DESC LIMIT $start_from, 10";
   $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);    

  foreach ($pageposts as $post) {  ....}
```

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This link has instructions on how to prevent timeouts from occurring.

https://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set

Add this to the top of your PHP script file, this will allow the script to run for 300 seconds.  Increase it as required.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Comment: I can't increase the 'max_execution_time' for some security reason.

Comment: Talk to your web hosting company about increasing the timeout.

Comment: I aksed about batch processing concept, so do you have any solutions regarding it. Thanks. ;)